# jquery PHP file upload causes browser memory usage to skyrocket

Tags: php, jquery, firefox

I have this jquery code:

```
$('input[type=file]').on('change', uploadFiles); 

function uploadFiles(event) {
    var data = new FormData();  
    var files = event.target.files;     
    for(var i = 0;i<files.length;i++){
        data.append("file_"+i, files[i]);
    }   
    data.append('dir_name',current_directory);
    apicall('upload.php','POST',data,fileUploaded); 
}
```

Then in php file:

```
<?php
$data = array();
$allFiles = scandir($_REQUEST['dir_name']);
if(isset($_FILES))
{  
    $error = false;
    $uploaddir = $_REQUEST['dir_name'];
    foreach($_FILES as $file)
    {
        echo $file['error'];
        echo $file['tmp_name'];
        $new_name = $file['name'];
        move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $uploaddir .'/'.$file['name']);
    }
}
else
{
    //some code here
}
echo json_encode($error);
?>
```

Now this works and everything, I can upload any file and multiple files at a time too. But it causes the memory Firefox uses to skyrocket and never come down again. It is proportional to the file I upload I think, but way way bigger. I read in the manual that `move_uploaded_file()` deletes the temporary file, so that can't be the problem. The only thing that helps is to close firefox and open it up again. Can somebody please tell me why this happens and how to make it stop?

If it matters, I am using XAMPP to test all this out on localhost.

This does not happen in chrome.